# Turn the server on Minecraft packet

Tags: ubuntu, wake-up, minecraft

#### What I'm looking for

A way to turn the server on when it receives a packet on Minecraft port.

I have a small Minecraft Spigot Server with tops 10 people playing on it. Currently it is the only thing that this PC does. I am running it on old i7-4930, 32 GB of RAM with Ubuntu Server 20.04 computer which drains a lot of power. I am also using Asus RT-AC68U router. I want to introduce some power savings. Turning off the machine is quite easy but waking it afterwards is much harder.

#### What I've tried

I was turning it on using WOL, but I had to do it manually every time from within network. So after some time I just left it turned on and it has been running for 31 days now.

I know it is possible to send WOL over the internet but I'm looking for more seamless implementation. Since Minecraft packets and Magic packets are completely different I wanted to implement some basic logic but couldn't find anywhere to do so on my router. Some pseudocode:

```
if (packet.Port == 25565) {
    if (server.Status == down) {
        sendMagicPacketTo(server);
    }
}
```

I wouldn't mind getting some extra controller (something cheap) to wake up the server if it would save some money on the long run. I was also thinking about using a Raspberry Pi to create a website to purely spin up the Minecraft Server, but it is similar solution to using WOL over Internet and it would make more sense to just use the Raspberry to host the server.

Comment: This depends on how sophisticated is your router. Which model is it?

Comment: Asus RT-AC68U with latest firmware

Comment: The router might have WOL built-in [like that](http://ec2-54-202-251-7.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/Main_WOL_Content.asp). See [this link](https://andblu.blogspot.com/2016/08/configure-wol-from-internet-wan-asus.html).